# Is it possible to develop Fleetboard app with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, fleetboard

On https://developer.fleetboard.com/#/getstarted, we can read

> To implement your ideas we recommend to use Android Studio.

But we work with Visual Studio, is it possible to use Xamarin ?

Comment: generally speaking, if you can do it in Android then you can do it in Xamarin Android

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

However we provide an SDK which makes it easier for you to use our library (access to vehicle data).
If you use Xamarin and want to use the provided functionality you have to integrate the jar on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any documentation or support for that ?